What is the Propagator associated to a homogeneous Cauchy problem?
I came across this problem:
Consider the following Cauchy problem on $\mathbb{R}_t\times\mathbb{R}_x^n$
$$\begin{cases}\partial_tu+\omega\cdot\nabla_xu=f(t,x),\\ u|_{t=0}=u_0(x)\end{cases}$$
where $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^n, u_0\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}_x^n)$ and $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_t;\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}_x^n))$.
a. Use the Fourier transform to define the propagator
$S(t)\colon u_0\mapsto u(t,\cdot)=S(t)u_0,$ associated to the homogenous problem with $f\equiv0$ and show that it yields an isometry $S(t):L^{2}(\mathbb{R}_{x}^{n})\to L^{2}(\mathbb{R}_{x}^{n})$.
b. Derive an explicit formula for the solution $u=u(t,x)$ when $f\neq0$.
I am a bit stuck because I don't know what the "propagator" is. I have not come across this in any PDE's book covering the Cauchy problem. Does anyone know what this is and/or how to solve the problem?

The term "propagator" does not really matter. I think the task is to apply the Fourier transform to $\partial_t u + \omega\cdot \nabla_x u = 0$. As a hint, $\mathcal{F}(\partial_t u)(t, k) = \partial_t \mathcal{F}(u)(t, k)$ by Leibniz-Formula. There is a similar, but a bit more non-trivial formula for $\mathcal{F}(\omega \cdot \nabla_x u)(t, k)$. Once you computed that, you have a very easy PDE that you can solve for $\mathcal{F}(u)$. Then retransform to get back $u$. $u$ is then of the form $S(t)u_0$ for an $S$ that you are supposed to find.

Btw: Sometimes, people call $S(t)$ the solution operator or solution semigroup
